# MongoDB and dynamic shard keys

Tags: mongodb, dynamic, key, sharding

I have been thinking about sharding with MongoDB and came across a use case which I haven't been able to figure out ... so here it is:

If I have documents that look like this one...

```
_id [Integer]
username [String]
password [String] <-- SHA1 hash
firstname [String]
lastname [String]
```

...and I now choose the password field as my shard key, it would be a good fit for sharding since it has a very high cardinality and would scale nicely. But the question remains, what happens if a user changes his password? Will the corresponding document be automatically migrated to a different chunk?

Does someone know how MongoDB handles cases like this one?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, shard keys are immutable.

Consider the mongo documentation, [Can I change the shard key after sharding a collection?](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/sharding/#can-i-change-the-shard-key-after-sharding-a-collection):

> Can I change the shard key after sharding a collection?
>
> No.
>
> There is no automatic support in MongoDB for changing a shard key
>   after sharding a collection. This reality underscores the importance
>   of choosing a good [shard key](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#shard-key). If you must change a shard key
>   after sharding a collection, the best option is to:
>
> - dump all data from MongoDB into an external format.
> - drop the original sharded collection.
> - configure sharding using a more ideal shard key.
> - [pre-split](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/) the shard key range to ensure initial even distribution.
> - restore the dumped data into MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your question is that you asked:

> what happens if a user changes his password?

Not:

> what happens if I change the shard key?

Completely different questions. For the second case the accepted answer is correct.

For your original question:

In shared clusters mongodb has a component called balancer. The balancer will balance your shards and migrate your chunks so they are balanced in size if possible.

Please read: [Sharded Cluster Balancer](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-balancer-administration/).

So, yes, if user changes their password the corresponding document will be automatically migrated to a different chunk, only if balancer thinks is needed. The balancer takes care of this.

Answer (score 1):

As an important note with the release of new version starting 4.2, the following statement does not apply.

> "Once inserted, a document's shard key value cannot be modified" .

So the answer to the question, **Can shard key be changed?**

> Although you cannot select a different shard key for a sharded collection, starting in MongoDB 4.2, you can update a document's shard key value unless the shard key field is the immutable _id field